# BusyIndicator in worklight not working properly

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I had recently ask this question:

Worklight busyindicator not working properly.My isssue is i'm using multipage.On page change i call adapter for webservice and call busy indicator so that it show work in progress while fetching.but what happen is page change and indicator show and hide quickly but adpater still in fetching phase and after sometime data called successfully but during these working no busy indicator shows.

```
var busyIndicator = null;

function wlCommonInit(){
busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator();
}
```

This is the code i call on page change.

```
    busyIndicatorDemo();
    var viewPath = "views/add_fund_transfer.html";
    WL.Page.load(viewPath,
        {
                onComplete: function() {    

                PayAnyOne_Controller.GetBranches(GetBranchesProcedureName);
                busyIndicator.hide();

            }
        });

function busyIndicatorDemo() {
    busyIndicator.show();
    setTimeout(15000);
}
```

its seems like busyindicator doesn't work with adpater when using in multipage. Please give me the solution or the problem in my code.

And got this reply:

when page has finished loading: invoke procedure (async call), and hide busyindicator.
So this generates the behavior you've reported - the busyindicator is shown and quickly hidden once the page has finished loading, even though the service is still fetching data (in an async call)

moving the busyindicator.hide to the onSuccess of the invoke procedure should solve the problem (put it also in the onFailure ...) Hope this helps

The Given solution is some how worked..but its happening now when i call the procedure busyindicator shows for few seconds and then disapear while the procedure still busy. i have done the above given solution. –

Comment: Firstly make sure you have upgraded your development environment to 5.0.6, where several busy indicator fixes have been made. If your troubles continue, update your post.

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as Answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A specific fix for a disappearing busy indicator during adapter invocation exist in Worklight v5.0.6, make sure you have updated your development environment to this version.

You can update directly from Eclipse, go to Help >> Check for updates.

Comment: im getting this error since i updated my worklight developer edition    "
Uncaught ReferenceError: wlInitOptions is not defined" and now application cant start

Comment: The solution regarding wlInitOptions is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549359/uncaught-referenceerror-wlinitoptions-is-not-defined  If your problem in this question is solved, please mark it as answered.