# Uncaught ReferenceError: wlInitOptions is not defined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm getting this error since i upgraded my worklight developer edition to v5.0.6:

```
wlclient init started worklight.js:1118
Uncaught ReferenceError: wlInitOptions is not defined
```

Comment: In the "js" folder in your application, is there an initOptions.js file? Compare your application structure to that of a new application. It sounds like your app structure is outdated (from which version did you upgrade to v5.0.6?)

Answer (score 2):

Look inside your application's js folder (yourProject\apps\yourApp\common\js). Make sure it contains an initOptions.js file and that its content is as follows (you can also create a new application and copy the file from there):

```
var wlInitOptions = {

    // # Should application automatically attempt to connect to Worklight Server on application start up
    // # The default value is true, we are overriding it to false here.
    connectOnStartup : false
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload',  function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); });
```

In addition, the HTML file must not contain a call to WL.Client.init in the `<body>` tag. It should look like this:

```
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: I did according to your instructions but this time the whole screen disapear and showing nothing....                              firebug shows:                                                 Console was cleared ripple.js:37
Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Gray. Hot.) ripple.js:37
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) chrome-extension://cnijnnaimeaacneklcndcafbnkeicckh/ripple.js
webworks.handset :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.) ripple.js:37
eula response:  true ripple.js:47

Comment: So now you also mention that Ripple is involved here? Great... How about editing your post with *all relevant information about what you've done*?

Comment: Dear Idan, Problem was from my side..mistakenly i had deleted the initOption.js refrence from my main html file..added and it worked..Thanks and sorry again ..Your solution was superb...

Comment: @user2076124, if your question is answered - please mark as answered. Thanks.