# ReferenceError: wlInitOptions is not defined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a worklight project. the project was working fine until i updated the worklight from 5.0.5 to 5.0.6.. I am getting the following error when i run the project in browser simulator.. I have not found a file initOptions.js in my file structure.. is it wlInitOptions.js or wlInitOptions is the variable in the file initOptions.js it is trying to find?

```
ReferenceError: wlInitOptions is not defined
```

Comment: See if the answer here helps, if not, add more information about what is your project and how and where this happens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549359/uncaught-referenceerror-wlinitoptions-is-not-defined

Comment: Your question doesn't contain *any* details to explain why it's different to the previous question you saw. People want to help, but nobody can read your mind. Why doesn't the answer on the other question work for you? Did you do anything else that didn't work?

Comment: I have a simple hybrid project with a login page, which was working before i updated worklight from 5.0.5 to 5.0.6. also, I am not finding any file called initOptions.js.. i manually added the file and tried the solution given by Idar, but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: If you do not find this file that your application's structure is all wrong. You may have removed it manually. See the linked question, and also compare a new application's structure to yours.

Comment: Dear Idan, do we specify this initOptions.js filename in any place, like to point that the initialization options are present in that particular file? or it is by default initOptions.js? I have not deleted the file by myself. 
The file name is initOptions.js or wlInitOptions.js ?