# TypeError: WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.setConnected is not a function

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i have upgraded my worklight with 5.0.5 to 5.0.6 .when i have worked on 5.0.5 it worked fine but the same code when i am using in updated version worklight 5.0.6 it gives me this error

TypeError: WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.setConnected is not a function 
WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.setConnected(false);

when i have build for the first time after upgrading to worklight 5.0.6 it gave this in the console

FWLST1061W: RMLight.java has changed, onCreate() was renamed to onWLCreate(), please check your code for changes. Refer to the IBM Worklight Information Center for details.

can some one help please

am also getting this error

ReferenceError: wlInitOptions is not defined
[Break On This Error]

if (!isIOSEnv() && wlInitOptions.connectOnStartup) {

Comment: Any possibility for you to attach the Worklight project for examination? This may be a certain scenario where the upgrader fails, can't tell for sure what is the reason.

Comment: hi Idan Adar i have modified the question can u tell me some reasons for getting this error .i dont have permissions to share my code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states: wlInitOptions is not defined. Could this indee be case? Please see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549359/uncaught-referenceerror-wlinitoptions-is-not-defined).

Look inside your application's js folder (yourProject\apps\yourApp\common\js). Make sure it contains an initOptions.js

Make sure this file is also referenced in the HTML.

Comment: thanks a lot Idan Adar this init problem resolved but now this new error is coming  response [/apps/services/api/RtmLight/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"responseID":"2","errors":["Runtime: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https:\/\/jazz.net refused"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/

worklight.js (line 1112)

Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://jazz.net refused

Comment: This is out of scope for this question. Please open a new question.

Comment: thank u Idan Adar i have opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056361/org-apache-http-conn-httphostconnectexception-connection-to-https-jazz-net-re