# IBM Worklight 5.0.x: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined

Tags: android, cordova, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-commerce

I am following this [WebSphere Commerce guide for Worklight store fronts](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/concepts/csmmobileappworklight.htm), to use Hybrid applications using IBM Worklight 5.0.5.

The application launches successfully, however after setting up the connection details for the store front in the app, and saving them - the store front, which is another Worklight Hybrid app located on a WebSphere Commerce server, is not initializing correctly.

Instead of loading correctly, I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined at 192.168.16.96/wcsstore/Aurora/mobile20/WorklightHybrid/android/js/initOptionsApp‌​‌​‌​.js:64
```

HTML File Code:

```
<body id="content" class="bg_splash" style="display: none;">
    <!-- application UI goes here -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="splashscreen" class="splash_logo_container splash_logo_position splash_logo"></div>
        <div id="pagePort" class="hidden"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/version.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_en_US.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_fr_FR.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_de_DE.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_it_IT.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_es_ES.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_pt_BR.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_zh_CN.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_zh_TW.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_ko_KR.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_ja_JP.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_ko_KR.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_ru_RU.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_ro_RO.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_pl_PL.js"></script>
    <script src="js/WCLocalStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="js/WCHybrid.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
</body>
```

initOptions.js

```
//Worklight Client initialization parameter array
var wlInitOptions = {
//Application should not attempt to connect to Worklight Server on application start up
connectOnStartup : false,
//Should application produce logs
enableLogger : true,
//Should direct updates prompt the user or occur silently
updateSilently: false
};

var initOptionsApp = (function() {

return {
    /**
     * Called when Cordova runtime has initialized
     */
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        var METHODNAME = "initOptionsApp.onDeviceReady";
        if (wlInitOptions.enableLogger) {
            WL.Logger.debug(METHODNAME, "ENTRY");
        }          
        //bind the hardware back button event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", WCHybridApp.onBackKeyDown, false);
        if (wlInitOptions.enableLogger) {
            WL.Logger.debug(METHODNAME, "EXIT");
        }
    }
};

})();

/**
* Bind the Worklight Client initialization call to the page load event
*/
if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }, false);
window.addEventListener('unload', function() { WCHybridApp.updateHistory(); }, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
window.attachEvent('onload',  function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); });
}

/**
 * Bind events to the Cordova deviceready event
 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", initOptionsApp.onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

**Edit:** The below was fixed after upgrading to Worklight 5.0.6.1

When I load my application on emulator its prompt unexpected three different dialog as can be seen in the images below.

[image]
More examples here:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2ynK.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/QClnN.png

Comment: please make sure that you have copied into WebSphere Commerce all required files from the correct version of Worklight. This is the only thing I believe that can cause t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting these Cordova-related dialogs usually means something is not right with the Cordova version you're using in your application.

I strongly suggest starting fresh with Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 (Juno SR2), and installing the Worklight Developer Edition (v5.0.6.1 from the Eclipse Marketplace). This will likely solve it.

**Edit:** From the edited question, it has.

The reamining issue with initOptions currently resembles this one: [Uncaught ReferenceError: wlInitOptions is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549359/uncaught-referenceerror-wlinitoptions-is-not-defined/)

Comment: Hi Idan, I didn't include any external library into the project. phoneGap lib come up with Worklight package after add environment. even its come up for simple Worklight project. I think you're right in saying to do fresh installation.

Comment: I know that... if you choose so, follow my suggestion.

Comment: hi Idan, the application looks load successfully on android but having an issue after loading a home page. its showing me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined at 192.168.16.96/wcsstore/Aurora/mobile20/WorklightHybrid/android/js/initOptionsApp.js:64 any idea why worklight object isn't initializing

Comment: Edit your question with your HTML and initOptions.js file.

Comment: This issue is starting to sound similar to this one, see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549359/uncaught-referenceerror-wlinitoptions-is-not-defined/

Comment: Thanks. It looks quite a modified one. Does the same issue also happen for a new application in 5.0.6.1, that you did not alter in any way?

Comment: You will note in a new application, that the reference to initOptions.js in the HTML file, is placed at the bottom - do the same in your application as well.

Comment: I did same for app but the same error? are any other steps to perform on Commerce Server to initialize Worklight instance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29608/discussion-between-idan-adar-and-saifuddin)